# Export From Access Subform Datasheet Including Unbound Control Source

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, export-to-excel, ms-access-2003

I have been searching this online for hours without luck. I have a subform embedded in my main form. The subform's recordsource is from a SQL result based on some filtering criteria user sets in the main form. After user clicks "Search", data gets populated in my subform. Most of its controls are then bound. However, I also have an unbound control in my subform. This unbound control gets data from a separate SQL based on the values of my other controls' values. Everything in my subform is presented in a datasheet view.

Now, I would like to design an "export" function that allows user to save the current search result in my subform datasheet into an Excel file. I have tried the following ways:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "my_Subform", acFormatXLS, exportFile & ".xls"
```

This only gives me the header of my subform without any data.

I have also tried to use CopyFromRecordset function. However, as I mentioned my subform has one control that is not bound to the record source of the subform. I can store the SQL object and do CopyFromRecordset, but this gives me only data from the bounded controls.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You are definately calling the OutputTo function after the queries have been run? and the data is in the datasheet view when you run it?

Comment: @JMG Yes, definitely. I have already had the data shown in my subform. That is done after my user clicks "Search" button. Then the "Export" button can be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this to work -- and with Unbound Field

1. The following is the syntax (obviously change the output path):

   `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, [Forms]![Main_form].Form.[Subform_XXX].Name, acFormatXLS, "C:\temp\exportSub.xls"`
2. The output XLS file had 4 columns - including the content of the Unbound.

Good Luck,
Wayne

Comment: thanks for the help. This does give me the column of unbound control, but as I mentioned there is only header exported with no data. I guess that is because my subform's recordsource is originally empty. It is set at run time after my user clicks "search" button. I don't know why the recordsource did not retain when the user later clicks "export" button.

Comment: My bad! I just noticed that I had placed a 'literal' in the unbound field. Just to confirm, you do know that any change to the unbound field on continuous forms will change all rows to be the same value?  Is that what you want, or do you want to have a different value for each row? Depending on user interfaces, could you just add a 'work' column to a table, then clear it when Access opens the form; then bind the 'work' column to the subform?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. My unbound field is updated by the other fields in the same row. I did this by setting the control source of the unbound field to a function that runs a SQL based on the value of two other bound fields in the form. I am not sure how the 'work' column can be implemented here. Could you explain further?

Comment: (Ugh! Hours of ice/tree removal!) Re a 'work' column, could you add a new column to one of the tables used by the form, then just have it bound to the unbound box?

Answer (score 0):

you may use MultiLevelExporter tool / add-in for MS Access for this. It can export data of Subform, including unbound control's data of the Subform into MS Excel.
Norbert